# Метод html() выводит лишнее

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте,у меня создается div он может передвигаться и менять размер,но когда я на него нажимаю(на клик у меня событие стоит,которое получает содержимое блока)он мне выводит много лишнего,если в div вывожу,то нормально,а если в alert или в textarea ,то лишнее.И почему Когда данные выводятся в Div ,то справа снизу появляется такой же "треугольничек" для растяжки блока,а также скроллы появляются.Как с этими скроллами бороться?
Заранее спасибо.
Здесь ссылка на код http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/u88nncLu/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
заменить

```
var soder=$(this).html();
```

на

```
var soder=$(this).text();
```

Почему вы видите мусор? Ваш див не пуст, как это может показаться. Дело в том, что вы подключаете плагины для ресайза и перетаскивания элемента(это, также ответ на вопрос - "снизу появляется такой же треугольничек"). Эти плагины добавляют в ваш div

```
<div id="div_1">
  1
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div> 
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
</div>
```

Используя $(element).html() можно получить все содержимое элемента вместе с потомками, тогда как $(element).text() - только контент блока.